# Assign the key's name from a PHP array to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, foreach

I'm a bit new to PHP and programming in general so please bear with me if I don't explain with the correct phrasing.

I am parsing an array into specific columns in order to later parse that data into a preexisting excel spreadsheet. Each array has specific keys that equate to specific columns.

The part I need help with is the following:

This is part of the array (it repeats this but with different data, an array for each):

```
{
  {
    "Batches": "24",
    "Timestamp": " ",
    "Manager": " ",
    "Region": " ",
    "Name": " ",
    "Cell": " ",
    "Email": " ",
    "Personalized or Blank": " ",
    "FNO's": " ",
    "Order Total": " ",
    "R289 FF Air": "0",
    "R289 T3": "0",
    "R399": "0",
    "R429": "0",
    "R489": "0",
    "R599": "0",
    "Openserve R549": "0",
    "Openserve R299": "0",
    "Vumatel": "0",
    "Octotel": "0",
    "Octotel T3": "0",
    "Balwin": "0",
    "Evotel": "1000",
    "Netstream": "0",
    "Metrofibre": "0",
    "Vodacom": "0",
    "TT Connect": "0",
    "WAN": "0",
    "Link Africa": "0",
    "Ambassador": "0",
    "Link Layer": "0",
    "Open Fibre": "0",
    "Zoom Fibre": "0"
  },
```

This is the loop:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($Data2022_23 as $item) {
    $A[$i] = $item['Order Total']; 
    $B[$i] = $item['Timestamp']; 
    $C[$i] = $item['Manager']; 
    $D[$i] = $item['Region']; 
    $E[$i] = $item['Name']; 
    $F[$i] = $item['Cell']; 
    $G[$i] = $item['Email']; 
    $H[$i] = $item['Personalized or Blank'];

    foreach($Data2022_23 as $key => $value) {
        if($key != "Batches" && $key != "Timestamp" && $key != "Manager" && $key != "Region" 
        && $key != "Name" && $key != "Cell" && $key != "Email" && $key != "Personalized or Blank" 
        && $key != "FNO's" && $key != "Order Total" && $value != "0"){
            $J = array_keys($Data2022_23, $key);
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

From $A to $H works, those are the specific columns, I need help with assigning $J the value of the key which is not 0, ie. "Evotel" as per the array above. I have tried tinkering the nested foreach loop in the code above but I am struggling to get the correct data output.

Any assistance will help.

I've tried different iteration of the nested for each loop, such as:

Assigning $J the $key, which return the index not the string.

```
$J = $key;
```

Trying a whole lot of tinkering on the foreach loop but none of it really worked.
I'm trying to get $J to have the value of the key, not the index which I keep getting.

Something like:

```
echo $J;
```

With result:

```
Array([0] => "Evotel")
```

or something like that.

Comment: What's wrong with $J[]= value; ???

Comment: For starters, your should replace those numerous `$key != "Batches" && $key != "Timestamp" && $key != ...` with _one_ `!in_array(...)`

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what result you actually want here. Is `$J` not supposed to be an array in the end, same as the other $A, $B etc.?

Comment: _"I need help with assigning $J the value of the key which is not 0, ie. "Evotel" as per the array above"_ - is that supposed to mean, that of all those keys after the first 8, only _one_ can have a non-0 value? Only you don't know which one it will be in each case - could be `Evotel` for the current item, and something else for the next?

Comment: @CBroe yeah that's it, it's not going to be the same for every array, it might be "Evotel", then "WAN", etc... The value I need assigned to the variable $J is the _string_ of the value that is **not == 0**. For example, if I printed $J it would need to return "Evotel", not the index value or the key value pair, I need it to be the string. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: If you just need the key, then do `$J = $key; break;` in the inner foreach loop ...? (Or `$J[$i] =`, if you want to keep it consistent with the rest of the arrays.)

Comment: Oh wow, it worked.

'
foreach($Data2022_23[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if($key != "Batches" && $key != "Timestamp" && $key != "Manager" && $key != "Region" 
        && $key != "Name" && $key != "Cell" && $key != "Email" && $key != "Personalized or Blank" 
        && $key != "FNO's" && $key != "Order Total" && $value != "0"){
            $J[$i] = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
'
It returns the string of the key value pair that has a value not == 0.
Thanks @CBroe